# Let $0\to\ker f\to A \xrightarrow fB\to C \to 0$ be an exact sequence of abelian groups. Can we say that $C\cong\operatorname{coker}f$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

> Let $f:A\to B$ be a group homomorphism between abelian groups.
> Let  $$0\to\ker f\to A\xrightarrow fB\to C\to0$$ be an exact sequence of abelian groups.
> Can we say that $C\cong \operatorname{coker}f$ ?

I think this does not hold in general, but I cannot find examples.

Comment: @pancini Yes, thank you .

Comment: The answer is yes. Let $g$ denote the surjection from $B$ onto $C,$ Then $C\cong B/\ker g=B/\operatorname{im}f.$

Comment: Do you assume that the middle arrow in the sequence is $f$? Because this is unclear to me. And if it is not, then this is not necessarily true.

Comment: Ofcourse, it is $f$.

Comment: Anyone can say, "I think this does not hold in general, but I cannot find examples." It doesn't take effort. This question is a PSQ.

Comment: You could simplify your question, replacing $0\to\ker f\to A\xrightarrow fB\to C\to 0$ with $A\xrightarrow fB\to C\to 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes. Let $g$ denote the surjection from $B$ onto $C,$ then $$C\cong B/\ker g=B/\operatorname{im}f.$$

Comment: Anyone can say, "I think this does not hold in general, but I cannot find examples." It doesn't take effort. This question is a PSQ.

Comment: All right then please @Pont, either improve your question or unaccept my answer so that I can delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g\colon B\to C$ be the given map. We know that $g$ is surjective, hence $B/\ker g\cong C$. But $\ker g=\operatorname{im} f$.